# Did I configure xmrig proxy correctly on my macbook? Am I even actually mining?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mining, hashrate, macos, xmrig

I think monero is based and wanted to try to mine it to any extent that I could. I used home brew, set up xmrig, etc, and now this is what I see in my terminal. Is that good? Did I do something wrong? Help.[image]